# Convert Wrongly Formatted HTML to CSV

Tags: html, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I have an html file which is in wrong format and I am trying to extract table data from the html file and convert it to csv file format , there is a snap of the html table below and I was trying to use beautifulsoup for extracting the table but this html file doesn't has  after reading first row.

### This is the link to html file : https://github.com/Gaurav7004/HTML_File/blob/main/HTML_File.html

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

outfile = open("table_data.csv","w",newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

# myhtml file
html = 'Report.html'

tree = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
table_tag = tree.findAll("table")[0]

tab_data = [[item.text for item in row_data.select("th,td")]
                for row_data in table_tag.select("tr")]

for data in tab_data:
    writer.writerow(data)
    print(' '.join(data))
```

---

Comment: Is the HTML badly formatted, or do you just want the data in a different format?

Comment: If you look at the html file the initial <tr> </tr> is working fine but after that there is no <tr> in the html file , but it is still opening in the web browser, I am confused.

Comment: Browsers will do heroic gyrations to present badly formatted tables to the user. check out the inspect version comparted to the source version of almost any table you see.

Comment: Since the table is lexically busted, maybe you can still get what you want by bypassing some of the expected structure. Given the input file, what output are you hoping for. Is the table a single row of data or are there additional rows that have not been shown?